# Do you need to install Git Windows to use Git Source Control Provider extension?

Tags: visual-studio, git

If I want to use [Git Source Control Provider](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/63a7e40d-4d71-4fbb-a23b-d262124b8f4c) do I need to install anything else like Git Windows or will Git Source Control Provider do it all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [the documentation](http://gitscc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Installation&referringTitle=Documentation), it seems pretty clear that you'll need to already have some form of git tools installed, since you have to provide paths to them.